# Directly proportional realtoinship between power consumed and time taken by computer system.

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, education

Suppose there is a computer system that performs some specific event in multiple iterations and requires some amount of power and time for each iteration to be calculated. At every iteration system learns from last iteration and in next iteration doesn't perform the calculation that is already performed in last iteration. So In that sense that system performs less calculations in every next iteration compared to previous.

Time taken for single iteration reduces with each iteration, So does the power consumed by system for each iteration also get reduced. In that hypothetical System, It it can be said that power consumed by each iteration is directly proportional to the time taken by each iteration.

How this power and time relationship can be described mathematically which shows that hypothetical system consumes power in directly proportional manner with time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: The answer really depends on "how much" the machine will learn with each iteration. Which is exactly what Oldboy said, so the question cannot be answered if we do not know explicitly the relationship between one iteration and the next.

Comment: Sir, it depends on the system how much it will learn, it could be 1% or 99%. There could be 1 iteration or 100 iteration (considering there is finite iterations). Just suppose if system takes less time for iterations the it should take less power too. Do not think about learn rate or number of iterations. so if such system exist then if iterations takes more time system takes more power. If iterations take less time system take less power. There should be directly proportional relation.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "Time taken for single iteration reduces with each iteration", that could mean anything. Any decreasing function will serve for the purpose. Depending on the type of the function, you can reach completely different conclusions.

For example, suppose that the first iteration takes exactly 1 second.

Suppose also that the second iteration takes 1/2 of the second, the third iteration 1/3 and so on... The total time (with infinitely many iterations) is $\sum_1^\infty\frac1n=\infty.$

If the next iteration takes one half of time spent on the previous one, the total time is $\sum_0^\infty\frac1{2^n}=2.$

So the end result could be... anything. And we even don't know if the number of iterations is finite or infinite. Your question looks more like a thought experiment rather than a real math problem.

Comment: Sir thanks for the answer, Yes it is an research problem, devolving a system that should not perform any calculation if it is already performed in previous iteration. My task is to extend the research. If event is performed successfully then it means execution ends, so definitely it is finite number of iteration (not considering scenario when iterations become infinite). Sir you gave me time required, I have already sorted out the time complexity for each iteration in multiple scenarios of finite iterations.

Comment: I am looking for some relation between time and power consumed. Suppose in every iteration system reduces its time for every next iteration and there for power consumed also get reduced hypothetically. There should be some directly proportional relation between time and power.